# HTTPS is required for GCM on iOS?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create an app with Cordova which receives push notifications from my server. Can anyone tell me that I need a https:// connection for the APNS to work or it should work with http:// as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All FCM/GCM endpoints are https, the same endpoints are used whether you are sending to Android, iOS or web so you should always use https when sending messages through FCM/GCM.

Comment: yes, the endpoint is https, but if I am sending the notifications from my custom website ex: http://www.myawesomewebsite.com will it work like this or I need https:///www.myawesomewebsite.com?

Comment: As long as HTTPS is used to make the request a domain is not necessary to make the request.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http), the sample POST request should be `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send`.

> A message request is made of 2 parts: HTTP header and HTTP body.
>
> The HTTP header must contain the following headers:
>
> - Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY
> - Content-Type: application/json for JSON; application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 for plain text. If
>     Content-Type is omitted, the format is assumed to be plain text.
>
> The HTTP body content depends on whether you're using JSON or plain
>   text.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-gcm-ios).